# Separating components by "type"?

Tags: component, reactjs

We have just started to work with React and some of my team mates proposed to split the components in 3 types (each one in its specific folder):

- components: reusable components like buttons, inputs and anything that would make sense as an open source shared component
- screens: pages of the application
- blocks: components that are specific to a page or section of the application,typically not reusable in more than 2 places

What do you think? Would it bring any benefit this kind of separation?
Is't not over engineering?
What are the downsides of this approach?

Comment: The creators recommend only splitting components into two piles, presentational components, responsible for rendering and layout, do not affect global state directly, do everything through props, may have simple internal state, and container components, which use presentational components, affect global state (stores). Everything above that is extra.

Comment: I'm of the same opinion, but they argue that having not reusable components mixed with reusable components can lead to confusion. Do you see downsides with this approach?

Comment: Well the connection still has to be made somewhere. Reusable components are the presentational components I mentioned, if you want to affect state from them, you have to pass callbacks through parameters. A good example are modal dialogs, where you do an operation on hitting the OK button, for example filter a table.

Comment: Actually, the "block" components wouldn't update the state, they are just components that don't make sense to have in several places because too specific...

Comment: It sound like the *block* components are composed of other components. I see nothing wrong with that. I believe React even encourages you to do so, start from small building blocks which you use to build larger ones.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, but separating them in different directories does?

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of the React ecosystem is that there is little or no opinion on how to structure your architecture.

So in general any structure is fine as long as you feel confortable with it.

If the question becomes **how do people generally structure their React application** a good start would be to analyze how the most popular boilerplates are set. You can get a list of those [here](http://andrewhfarmer.com/starter-project/).

[kriasof's boilerplate](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) which is the one with most stars right now, puts everything in the `components` folder except components that have to be referenced by the react router. Those components are defined close to the route.